# How to create a wrapper for TextAsset and assign it in ScriptedImporter?

Tags: unity, c#

I would like to create a wrapper for `TextAsset` class to be able to use `Resources.Find(All)<MyTextAssetWrapper>("")` in order to filter out the assets. So, I've made a simple wrapper:

```csharp
class MyTextAssetWrapper : TextAsset
{
    public MyTextAssetWrapper(string text) : base(text) { }
}
```

But the problem appears after I do `ScriptedImporter`:

```csharp
[ScriptedImporter(1, "foo")]
class CustomTextImporter : ScriptedImporter
{
    public override void OnImportAsset(AssetImportContext ctx)
    {
        var customText = new MyTextAssetWrapper(File.ReadAllText(ctx.assetPath));
        ctx.AddObjectToAsset("Custom Text", pgnAsset);
        ctx.SetMainObject(customText);
    }
}
```

But, both in the inspector and by calling the `GetType()` on the imported asset shows `TextAsset` as a type. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You mention calling `GetType()` but that call isn't in your example code. Please update the question and add the code where you're calling `GetType()`.